# color cells of pandoc table

Tags: r, pdf, knitr, r-markdown

I have this table that I would like to render in PDF using PANDOC in an RMD file

```
 table = data.frame(category = c("A","B","C"), groupA = c(.2,.3,.5), groupB= c(.6,.7,.9))
 table
 pandoc.table(table,split.table = Inf,keep.line.breaks = TRUE)

----------------------------
 category   groupA   groupB 
---------- -------- --------
    A        0.2      0.6   

    B        0.3      0.7   

    C        0.5      0.9   
----------------------------
```

How can I color the cells of the "groupA" and "groupB" columns with conditional formatting like:

```
>0 and <= .2    = "green"
>.2 and <= .3    = "red"
>.3 and <= .4    = "blue"
>.4 and <= .5     = "orange"
>.5 and <= .6     = "yellow"
>.6 and <= .7     = "black"
>.7 and <= .8     = "brown"
>.8  = "white"
```

Comment: To render to HTML or PDF? If the former, check out [formattable](https://renkun.me/formattable/).

Comment: I cannot use formattable becasue it is PDF

Answer (score 2):

If you're rendering to PDF, you (or someone else's function) have to format your table with LaTeX. While there are plenty of helpful packages and functions that will do all the work for you (`knitr::kable`, `xtable`, `stargazer`), if you need fine-grained control, you may need to edit LaTeX yourself, at least in part.

A reasonably painless option is `Hmisc::latex`, which will create the table from the data.frame, and has a parameter (among many) `cellTexCmds` that allows passing styling for individual cells via a matrix of similar dimensions to the data.frame. The `file` parameter to `''` so it doesn't save a file, and `where = '!htbp'` so the table appears in the correct place in the document. To set cell background color, you'll need the `xcolor` or `colortbl` LaTeX packages, which can be loaded in the YAML frontmatter.

To eliminate the LaTeX comment, capture the output, subset, and print, or just use .Rnw instead of .Rmd.

````r
---
title: "Conditional Formatting"
header-includes:
   - \usepackage[table]{xcolor}
output:
  pdf_document: default
---


```{r}
df <- data.frame(category = c("A","B","C"), 
                 groupA = c(.2,.3,.5), 
                 groupB= c(.6,.7,.9))

df.format = matrix('', nrow = nrow(df), ncol = ncol(df))

df.format[, -1] <- paste0('cellcolor{', 
                          sapply(df[-1], function(x){
                              cut(x, breaks = c(0, seq(.2, .8, by = .1), 1), 
                                  labels = c('green', 'red', 'blue', 'orange', 
                                             'yellow', 'black', 'brown', 'white'))}),
                          '}')

df.format
```

```{r table, results='asis'}
cat(capture.output(
    Hmisc::latex(df, file = '', cellTexCmds = df.format, where = "!htbp")
    )[-1])
```
````

[image: pdf image with formatted cells]

Comment: I cant have this "%latex.default(df, file = “”, cellTexCmds = df.format, where = “!htbp”)%"   showing.  do you know any other option to using rmd?

Comment: `latex` is designed to write to a file, so you could write a file and import it with `readLines`, skipping the first line. However, trying to get it to write a file is making R hang for me for unexplained reasons, so a perhaps simpler workaround is to capture the output, subset, and print: `cat(capture.output(
    Hmisc::latex(df, file = '', cellTexCmds = df.format, where = "!htbp"))[-1])`

Comment: `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}` caused problems on my (non R) pandoc, because xcolor was already loaded in the default.latex template. So, I tried using `\PassOptionsToPackage{table}{xcolor}` in the `header-includes` which, although didn't cause an error, had no effect because again the default.latex was using `\PassOptionsToPackage` with xcolor. My solution was to copy the default.latex template and modify it, using `--template=` to point to it on the pandoc command.